# System.InvalidOperationException: Tried to add property 'Name' when already added

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm really struggling to get my first NHibernate project off of the ground, I think that my issues revolve mainly around Enums. I am currently getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Tried to add property 'Name' when already added.
```

I have downloaded the Fluent NHibernate source and set a breakpoint where the exception occurs and have been able to pin it down to be something to do with EnumStringType.

I have the following class defined:

```
public class CurrencyStringType : EnumStringType<Currency>
{
}
```

And the following enumeration:

```
public enum Currency
{
    GBP = 826,
    USD = 840,
    EUR = 978
}
```

Which is used by this part of the Model:

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int JobId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), MaxLength(3)]
    public virtual Currency Source { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3), MaxLength(3)]
    public virtual Currency Target { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var t = obj as ExchangeRate;

        if (t == null)
            return false;

        if (this.Job == t.Job & this.Source == t.Source && this.Target == t.Target)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.JobId + "|" + this.Source + "|" + this.Target).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Mapping Override as follow:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<ExchangeRate> mapping)
{
    // Define the composite key
    mapping.CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(e => e.JobId, "JobId")
        .KeyReference(e => e.Source)
        .KeyReference(e => e.Target);
}
```

I have been struggling for over 2 days now to try and get my Enums working with Fluent NHibernate - it seems insanely complicated for some reason.

**Update: I created a new Mapping Override as follows...**

```
public class CurrencyStringTypeMap : IAutoMappingOverride<CurrencyStringType>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<CurrencyStringType> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(m => m.Name);
    }
}
```

As expected it overcomes the initial exception however it is simply replaced with the same but for another property which also belongs to EnumStringtype which makes me think that perhaps there is a bug somewhere? The new exception after adding the above override is as follows:

```
Tried to add property 'PrimitiveClass' when already added
```

---

I eventually resolved this with the following manual mapping class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the mapping for ExchangeRates
/// </summary>
public class ExchangeRateMap : ClassMap<ExchangeRate>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ExchangeRateMap"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ExchangeRateMap()
    {
        Table("ExchangeRates");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(e => e.JobId, "JobId")
            .KeyProperty(e => e.Source, "Source")
            .KeyProperty(e => e.Target, "Target");
        Map(e => e.Rate);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to post your mapping.

Comment: Thanks @ColeW - I am using Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping however I do have an override and have updated the post with this detail now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you should map `Source` and `Target` using the `KeyReference()` method. I've never done what you're trying to do here, so take what I write with a grain of salt.

I typically don't use the auto-mapping feature, preferring to map my entities manually. In those cases, I `Map()` the enum property, and FNH uses an `NVARCHAR` type. I specify the `Length` and `Not.Nullable()`.

So, based on this experience, I would try using `KeyProperty()` or `Mapped()` and see what happens. Short of that, search SO for composite ID problems and you'll find a post talking about using an actual composite class as the identifier, instead of properties of the entity itself.

I'd also consider manually mapping this class.